# OpenCV / JavaCV slower in Linux than Windows

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision, javacv

I am using JavaCV to build a face detection application.  I am new to using OpenCV but having constructed a basic application, the same code is much slower in Linux than Windows.

To test, I am only using an OpenCVFrameGrabber to capture from the webcam (not processing or displaying the stream).

Using exactly the same hardware (dual boot PC) and exactly the same code:
On Windows 7 this results in <10% CPU usage
On Ubuntu 14.04 this takes ~40-60% CPU

JavaCV version 0.8 using OpenCV 2.4.9-0.8

Does anybody have an idea why this is the case?

Edit: Added profile - All CPU time seems to be consumed inside OpenCV (cvGrabFrame)
[image]

Comment: Are both on the same JDK or in the Linux is on the OpenJDK and in the windows is on the oracle one?

Comment: Both Oracle JDK7 64bit.  I have also tried in Linux using 32bit JDK but the same results.

Comment: Profile. Any comment on performance without profile data is usually inane speculation.

Comment: Very true - I've added the profiler output to the post